# Convert a 3d graphic into rgb array

Tags: arrays, matlab, opencv, ffmpeg, 3d

Im working on a project that has 3d led cube (256*256*256).What software do i use to design the 3D model and for projecting the same on the LED cube.The LED used is RGB but the answer need not be for RGB. Even monochromatic LED is also fine.
Ive tried checking for MATLAB , FFMPG , OPENCV and AUTOCAD.But none of then help.

Objective : CREATE 3D MODEL => GENERATE MATRIX/ARRAY of colors => Project the matrix onto LED cube.
The generator has to be dynamic such that any changes in to 3d model should reflect on the LED cube.Any well known simulator as such is encouraged.Please count on the above mentioned software if they can do the same, image processing through matlab/opencv is new for me.

Input file : graphic 3D model drawn.
Output file : array of representation of color(any).

Comment: not sure what an led cube is, but maybe you don't want to "project" the 3d model, but instead want transform it to a "volumetric" 3d object?

Comment: Led cube is an arrangement of led in a 3D format that looks like a cube with each led as a coordinate.I should be able to play any animation of that order..

Comment: do you already know what exactly you want to compute, or is this part of your question / research? I have multiple quite different intuitions of what you could do...